# PostMessage Ctrl+V without raising the window

Tags: c, windows

I maintain the Vim-R-plugin, and, until the last released version, on Windows, I was using Python to copy R code from the Vim text editor into the Windows clipboard and then paste it into R Console Window without raising the R Console window. The Python code used to send Ctrl+V to R Console was:

```
def CntrlV():
    global RConsole
    win32api.keybd_event(0x11, 0, 0, 0)
    try:
        win32api.PostMessage(RConsole, 0x100, 0x56, 0x002F0001)
    except:
        RConsole = 0
        pass
    if RConsole:
        time.sleep(0.05)
        try:
            win32api.PostMessage(RConsole, 0x101, 0x56, 0xC02F0001)
        except:
            pass
    win32api.keybd_event(0x11, 0, 2, 0)
```

On the development version of the plugin, I transfered most code that was written in Python to a C library to avoid making the plugin dependent on Python. However the code below, which is my attempt of translating the Python code, is not working:

```
keybd_event(0x11, 0, 0, 0);
if(!PostMessage(RConsole, 0x100, 0x56, 0x002F0001))
    RConsole = NULL;
if(RConsole){
    Sleep(0.05);
    PostMessage(RConsole, 0x101, 0x56, 0xC02F0001);
}
keybd_event(0x11, 0, 2, 0);
```

What C code on Windows can be used to send Ctrl+V to a window that is not in the foreground and that may even be minimized?

Answer (score 1):

You can only paste to the focused window if you're going to simulate a keyboard event.

You may be able to system windows enumerate windows; find the window you're pasting to and use a `WM_SETTEXT` instead?

Comment: I have found some comments on the web saying that WM_SETTEXT does not work with PostMessage.

Comment: Microsoft has changed the system block app's from doing these sorts of things. Have you researched window hook procedures? That may be your best bet

Comment: The code written in Python was developed on Windows XP and still works on Windows 8. I think I do not need a hook procedure because I do not want to monitor the operating system. I need to send a message from one application to another.

Comment: I thought maybe something things mentioned here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4610/Three-Ways-to-Inject-Your-Code-into-Another-Proces could be helpful